# Laptop lcd freezes and fades white sometimes (or short horizontal lines on black background), does this indicate a problem with the LVDS cable?

Tags: lcd, laptop

-->[Video of the problem](https://youtu.be/0EQQKgEUAj8)

Laptop: Asus K95VB

Lifetime: 2,5 years old

Lcd problem: sometimes

Asus replaced the lcd a half year ago under warranty because there where [thrips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrips) inside the lcd.
(I had no problems for a few months afther the replacement).
I have no problems on an external monitor with vga, So i think it's not the graphics card.
I have already checked the connection with the motherboard, but i still did not open the screen.

Do you think the LVDS cable is not properly connected (at the back of the lcd)? Or can it be something else?

I want to fix it myself because it's no longer under warranty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be the LVDS cable. However it is more likely the thermally bonded flex cables that go from the LVDS connector board to the panel components themselves. In the latter case there is very little that can be done short of just replacing the complete panel.

Personally with the low costs of pretty nice high performance laptops and convertibles today I think money may very well be spent on a new unit.